# App to App communication witout using push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service

Is there any possibility app to app communication without using push notification?
I want to send an image from one app to another,some suggestion and advice will be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Are they installed in same device ? If this is the case then http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: no, in separate devices..

Comment: Why you need to do it without push notification?
Would be nice to post your intent behind this.

Comment: becoze the devices use gprs,and gprs is very slow to send and get data from server,i just want to know is there any possibility is available to share image or file app to app communication..i hope u got my point.